# Find trailing slash and delete all after it then delete slash

Tags: php, regex, string

I have a URL that looks as follows:

```
https://db.ygoprodeck.com/card/Qliphort%20Shell/
```

In my php code, I trim everything after card the code to get the name (for setting SEO tags):

```
$cname = $_SERVER['REQUEST_URI'];
$cname = substr($cname, strpos($cname, "card/") +6);   
$cname = substr($cname, 0, -1);
```

This is working as intended.
The issue is, when I link to this subdomain from my main domain, Google Analytics adds on a tag at the end:

```
https://db.ygoprodeck.com/card/Qliphort%20Shell/?_ga=2.211230173.973474856.1550500277-1234167223.1550500277
```

So now my SEO tags are affected when this happens.
I need to be careful with removing slashes as there can often be a name that contains a slash:

```
https://db.ygoprodeck.com/card/D/D/D%20Rebel%20King%20Leonidas/
```

I need to locate the last slash and remove everything after it, then I can use something like rtrim to remove the last slash.

```
$newurl= rtrim($url,'/');
```

Any ideas?

Comment: Maybe `preg_replace('~/[^/]+/?$~', '', $s)`?

Comment: That works when the google analytics tag is added at the end but it takes too much when the tag isn't present.  On a URL like this: https://db.ygoprodeck.com/card/D/D/D%20Flame%20High%20King%20Genghis/ it will only leave D/D

Comment: So, what is the pattern rule? When start matching?

Comment: I figured it out. I can just do a check then apply what you told me. if(strpos($string, '?_ga'))

Comment: `parse_url` works fine with partial URLs such as `/card/Qliphort%20Shell/?_ga=…`, so I’d suggest you start with that, so that you get the URL path on its own for easier manipulation.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can get position of the last slash by *strrpos()* method and then you just remove the string after that position by *substr_replace()*

like,

```
$url = "https://db.ygoprodeck.com/card/Qliphort%20Shell/?_ga=2.211230173.973474856.1550500277-1234167223.1550500277";
echo $new = substr_replace($url,'',strrpos($url, '/'));
```

Thank you.

Comment: Does the job in one go. Thank you!